# How to tell binary from text files in linux

Tags: linux, binary, diff, ascii

The linux `file` command does a very good job in recognising file types and gives very fine-grained results. The `diff` tool is able to tell binary files from text files, producing a different output.

Is there a way to tell binary files form text files? All I want is a yes/no answer whether a given file is binary. Because it's difficult to define binary, let's say I want to know if `diff` will attempt a text-based comparison.

To clarify the question: I do not care if it's ASCII text or XML as long as it's text. Also, I do not want to differentiate between MP3 and JPEG files, as they're all binary.

Comment: If you're happy with the way that `diff` decides which files are text and which are binary, then you could always just look at the source of `diff` and see how they implement it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [diff manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_mono/diff.html#Binary) specifies that

> diff determines whether a file is text
>   or binary by checking the first few
>   bytes in the file; the exact number of
>   bytes is system dependent, but it is
>   typically several thousand. If every
>   byte in that part of the file is
>   non-null, diff considers the file to
>   be text; otherwise it considers the
>   file to be binary.

Comment: this seems to be a good heuristics. `svn` does the same thing as noted by Christoffer below

Answer (score 13):

`file` is still the command you want. Any file that is text (according to its heuristics) will include the word "text" in the output of `file`; anything that is binary will not include the word "text".

If you don't agree with the heuristics that `file` uses to determine text vs. not-text, then the question needs to be better specified, since text vs. non-text is an inherently vague question. For example, `file` does not identify a PGP public key block in ASCII as "text", but you might (since it is composed only of printable characters, even though it is not human-readable).

Comment: the output of `file` does not always contain the word "text", e.g. it's not the case for XML files. however `file -i` will give the mime type, which indeed contains the word "text"

Comment: When I execute `file` on an XML document, it reports "XML document text". Perhaps the one you're testing with includes encoded binary data that file doesn't think is text?

Comment: @gabor i actually get the opposite effect. When I use -i i get for xmls `application/xml; charset=us-ascii` so the `grep -v text` doesn't filter it out. Without -i it works fine

Comment: @Hilikus what system are you on? file from 1:5.37-5ubuntu0.1 package shows text/xml

Comment: I think the most reliable option is something like this: `file -i <file> | grep -q -e text -e ascii`.  Relying only on `text` also fails for `JSON`.

Answer (score 6):

A quick-and-dirty way is to look for a `NUL` character (a zero byte) in the first K or two of the file.  As long as you're not worried about UTF-16 or UTF-32, no text file should ever contain a `NUL`.

**Update**: According to the diff manual, this is exactly what diff does.

Comment: (If you're not settled somewhere in Asia,) I'd go with this approach.

Answer (score 4):

This approach defers to the `grep` command in determining whether a file is binary or text:

```
is_text_file() { grep -qIF '' "$1"; }
```

### grep options used:

- `-q`  Quiet; Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found
- `-I`  Process a binary file as if it did not contain matching data
- `-F`  Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.

### grep pattern used:

- `''`  Empty string. All files (except an empty file)
  will match this pattern.

### Notes

- An empty file is not considered a text file according to this test. (The GNU `file` command agrees with this assessment.)
- A file with one printable character, say `a`, is considered a text file according to this test. *(Makes sense to me.)* (The `file` command disagrees with this assessment. (Tested with GNU `file`))
- This approach requires only one child process to test whether a file is text or binary.

### Test

```sh
# cd into a temp directory
cd "$(mktemp -d)"

# Create 3 corner-case test files
touch empty_file       # An empty file
echo -n a >one_byte_a  # A file containing just `a`
echo a >one_line_a     # A file containing just `a` and a newline

# Another test case: a 96KiB text file that ends with a NUL
head -c 98303 /usr/share/dict/words > file_with_a_null_96KiB
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 >> file_with_a_null_96KiB

# Last test case: a 96KiB text file plus a NUL added at the end
head -c 98304 /usr/share/dict/words > file_with_a_null_96KiB_plus1
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 >> file_with_a_null_96KiB_plus1

# Defer to grep to determine if a file is a text file
is_text_file() { grep -qI '^' "$1"; }

# Test harness
do_test() {
  printf '%22s ... ' "$1"
  if is_text_file "$1"; then
    echo "is a text file"
  else
    echo "is a binary file"
  fi
}

# Test each of our test cases
do_test empty_file
do_test one_byte_a
do_test one_line_a
do_test file_with_a_null_96KiB
do_test file_with_a_null_96KiB_plus1
```

#### Output

```
            empty_file ... is a binary file
            one_byte_a ... is a text file
            one_line_a ... is a text file
file_with_a_null_96KiB ... is a binary file
file_with_a_null_96KiB_plus1 ... is a text file
```

On my machine, it seems grep checks the first 96 KiB of a file for a `NUL`. (Tested with GNU `grep`). The exact crossover point depends on your machine's page size.

Relevant source code: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?h=v3.6#n1550

Answer (score 3):

You could try to give a

```
strings yourfile
```

command and compare the size of the results with the file size ... i'm not totally sure, but if they are the same the file is really a text file.

Comment: Where 'definitely' depends on the implementation of the `strings` command. But, yes, +1 for the idea.

Comment: I said "not totally sure" just for the implementation issue, but on a general note it should work .

Comment: +1, this would work on most GNU platforms. `strings file | wc.c` then `wc -c file`.

Comment: any way to do it without creating a temporary file? also, large files could pose an issue here

Comment: strings file | head -c <bytes you want to check> | wc -c

and compare to wc -c file

Answer (score 1):

These days the term "text file" is ambiguous, because a text file can be encoded in ASCII, ISO-8859-*, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 and so on.

See [here](http://help.collab.net/topic/faq/svnbinary.html) for how Subversion does it.

Comment: But literally *everything* uses bytes > 0x7F today, even translated man pages or ISO-8859 text files. This would exclude way too much, that is, every non-ASCII text file. Since there is, however, an almost disappearing probability to see a \0 in a text file, RichieHindle's approach seems more appropriate to me (that is, for every file written since the early 80s).

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to do this in ubuntu is use nautilus in the "list" view. The type column will show you if its text or binary

Answer (score -1):

Commands like less, grep detect it quite easily(and fast). You can have a look at their source.