# How to exclude binaries when using rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to rsync a directory to server from a mac machine to linux machine while excluding compiled files like .o files and binary executables.  How do I exclude binary files?

What I am using at the moment:

```
rsync -av --compress --exclude="*.o" dir server:dir
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sticky problem because a Unix system does not have a hard and fast definition of the distinction between "binary" and "text" files. You can do a pretty good job by using the `file` command and searching for `text` in the output (see [How to tell binary from text files in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644938/how-to-tell-binary-from-text-files-in-linux)), so I'd run `find` to generate a list of files which `file` considers to be text, and use that as the list of files to rsync:

```
find dir | xargs file | awk -F: '$2 ~ /text/ { print $1 }' | \
    rsync --files-from=- -av --compress dir server:dir
```

This will require some tweaking to make sure the pathnames are correct relative to the source dir, and so on, but it should get close to what you want.

In the long term, I'd want to rework my build process to put generated files in a `dir/build` directory, but this might help for now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.cvsignore` file in the directories and use the option `-C` to `rsync`.

But this is only vaguely what you specified.  Maybe it suits you well, maybe it assumes other things than you.  So be careful and test that properly.

Also, you can run a `find` before the `rsync`, scanning the complete tree for files matching your idea of being "binary" (maybe compiled executables?), and place all their names in an exclude file which you then use with option `--exclude-from`.